# Increase size and font size of a Gantt-chart in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: beamer, gantt

I have created a Gantt-chart in a beamer presentation (with the help of this forum btw). But I want to make it a little bigger - it seems it could be a little bigger and still fit on the slight, however, I have already set its width to `\textwidth`. Also, I want to increase the fontsize a little bit. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Metropolis}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Gantt-Chart}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{.7\textheight},center}
        \begin{ganttchart}[
            hgrid,
            vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},{dotted}},
            vrule/.style={very thick, red},
            x unit=0.125cm,
            time slot format=isodate,
            time slot unit=day,
            calendar week text = {W\currentweek{}},
            bar height = 0.6, %necessary to make it fit the height
            bar top shift = 0.2, %to move it inside the grid space ;)
            bar label node/.append style={align=left,text width={width("This is my longest task")}},
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=cyan},
            progress label text = \relax
            ]{2019-02-11}{2019-07-21}
            \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week} \\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task1}{2019-02-11}{2019-02-17}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task2}{2019-03-14}{2019-03-14}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task3}{2019-04-01}{2019-04-14}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task4}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-15}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task5}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-21}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}, progress = 20]{Task6}{2019-04-22}{2019-05-26}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task7}{2019-05-27}{2019-06-09}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task8}{2019-06-10}{2019-06-30}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task9}{2019-04-01}{2019-07-15}
            \ganttvrule{2019-07-15}{2019-07-15}
        \end{ganttchart}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: whops, just realized: Simply increasing its height seems to increase the entire chart a little as well

Answer (score 2):

Your are scaling down your diagram to fill the whole available textwidth, there is no room to make it larger unless you either make the margins smaller or safe space within the diagram, for example by adjusting the position of the bar labels:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Gantt-Chart}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}
        \begin{ganttchart}[
            hgrid,
            vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},{dotted}},
            vrule/.style={very thick, red},
            x unit=0.125cm,
            time slot format=isodate,
            time slot unit=day,
            calendar week text = {W\currentweek{}},
            bar height = 0.6, %necessary to make it fit the height
            bar top shift = 0.2, %to move it inside the grid space ;)
            bar label node/.append style={align=left,text width={width("Task1 ")}},
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=cyan},
            progress label text = \relax
            ]{2019-02-11}{2019-07-21}
            \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week} \\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task1}{2019-02-11}{2019-02-17}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task2}{2019-03-14}{2019-03-14}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task3}{2019-04-01}{2019-04-14}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task4}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-15}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task5}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-21}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}, progress = 20]{Task6}{2019-04-22}{2019-05-26}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task7}{2019-05-27}{2019-06-09}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task8}{2019-06-10}{2019-06-30}\\
            \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task9}{2019-04-01}{2019-07-15}
            \ganttvrule{2019-07-15}{2019-07-15}
        \end{ganttchart}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i would not use `adjustbox` for fit diagram on frame, rather would made small changes in Gantt diagram as are defining used fonts as `\tiny`, use smaller units etc. also remove a `bar/.append style={...}` from `\ganttbar` command and replace it where necessary with option `progress=...`. changes are in code indicated with `% <---`. obtained diagram is still wider than available text width, however with locally changed text width it can be nicely centered in frame:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{changepage}             % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Gantt-Chart}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em}
\centering
    \begin{ganttchart}[
    hgrid,
    vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},{dotted}},
    vrule/.style={very thick, red},
    x unit=0.7mm,                   % <---
    y unit title=2.4ex,             % <---
    y unit chart=2.0ex,             % <---
    time slot format=isodate,
    time slot unit=day,
    calendar week text = {W\currentweek{}},
    bar height = 0.4,               % <---
    vrule label font=\tiny,         % <---
    title label font=\tiny,         % <---
    bar label font=\tiny,           % <---
    bar/.append style={fill=blue},              % <---
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=cyan},   % <---
    progress label text = \relax
                    ]{2019-02-11}{2019-07-21}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week}         \\
    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Task1}{2019-02-11}{2019-02-17}\\  % <---
    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Task2}{2019-03-14}{2019-03-14}\\  % <---
    \ganttbar{Task3}{2019-04-01}{2019-04-14}            \\  % <---
    \ganttbar[progress=0]{Task4}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-15}\\  % <---
    \ganttbar{Task5}{2019-04-15}{2019-04-21}            \\  % <---
    \ganttbar[progress=20]{Task6}{2019-04-22}{2019-05-26}\\ % <---
    \ganttbar{Task7}{2019-05-27}{2019-06-09}            \\  % <---
    \ganttbar{Task8}{2019-06-10}{2019-06-30}            \\  % <---
    \ganttbar{Task9}{2019-04-01}{2019-07-15}                % <---
    \ganttvrule{2019-07-15}{2019-07-15}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```