# Streching Tabularx horizontally

Tags: tables, margins, tabularx

I have created a table with `tabularx` environment inside of LaTeX.

However, my problem is that if I try to make it larger than `\textwidth`, the `tabularx` is not centered anymore. What I need is a centered table with a horizontal length that equals the width of the page. However, my aim is to not to increase the separation between words to do that. I simply aim to write more words horizontally.

Below is my code. I had to take out the actual sentences. How can I do this?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
\hline
        \textbf{Restrictions} & \textbf{Future Suggestion} \\ 
\hline
        1. dummy text & 1. dummy text    \\
        2. dummy text & 2. dummy text \\ 
        3. dummy text.& 3. dummy text \\
        4. dummy text & 4. dummy text \\
        5. dummy text & 5. dummytext   \\ 
    \end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you like to have table wider than `\textwidth, you need to increase `\textwidth inside float. For example by use of the `changepage` package. BTW, Avoid to use `H` placement of floats (using it, it not float anymore).

Comment: Do not use svalebox but a

Comment: @Zarko, can you give a short example of how I can use changepage?

Comment: Never scale a table as this produce inconsistent sizes of fonts an rules, just add a standard smaller font as `\footnotesize`. On the other hand, if the column contents are unven, using tabulary instead of tabularx (e.g.  \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{RLCJ} could help to fit  a big table).

Comment: Search this site for `changepage`. Also, the packet documentation well describe its use. For writing  an example you need first extend your code fragment to complete small document, which show your problem. Some exampšle you can find in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672788/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478496/, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code fragment follows, that your table width is smaller than `\textwidth`, but in text you say that it is bigger. It would be more clear, what is your problem, if you would extend this code fragment to complete small document, which we can test it as it is.

So, as I mentioned in my comment, one of possible solutions is to use `changepage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-4em}{-4em}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X}   % instead of \textwidth is used \linewidth!
\hline
        \textbf{Restrictions} & \textbf{Future Suggestion} \\
\hline
        1. dummy text & 1. dummy text   \\
        2. dummy text & 2. dummy text   \\
        3. dummy text.& 3. dummy text   \\
        4. dummy text & 4. dummy text   \\
        5. dummy text & 5. dummytext    \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
    
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: yes, exactly. Thanks a lot